# php date function and calculating days of the week to ensure weekends get skipped

Tags: php, sql

I've set up this rotating calendar yesterday and i figured i might run into problems with it and sure enough today the problem occurred that i expected. The dates shifted when the days changed. Instead of it skipping the weekend like it did yesterday it showed Saturday instead of Monday. It's only suppose to show Monday - Friday and than +3 and back to Monday - Friday.  Example code:

```
echo "Today";
echo date('m/d'); 
echo "<br>";
echo substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+1 day')), 0, 2). date('m/d', strtotime('+1 day')); 
echo "<br>";
echo substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+2 day')), 0, 1). date('m/d', strtotime('+2 day'));
echo "<br>";
echo substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+5 day')), 0, 1). date('m/d', strtotime('+5 day'));
echo "<br>";
echo substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+6 day')), 0, 1). date('m/d', strtotime('+6 day'));
echo "<br>";
echo substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+7 day')), 0, 1). date('m/d', strtotime('+7 day'));
echo "<br>";
echo substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+8 day')), 0, 2). date('m/d', strtotime('+8 day'));
echo "<br>";
echo substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+9 day')), 0, 1). date('m/d', strtotime('+9 day'));
echo "<br>";
echo substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+12 day')), 0, 1). date('m/d', strtotime('+12 day'));
echo "<br>";
echo substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+13 day')), 0, 1). date('m/d', strtotime('+13 day'));
```

Obviously mode is not getting the job done, how can i ensure that the weekends are always skipped?

Additionally, I'm concating this into a sql query like so: (actual code)

```
sum(case when cast(a.follow_up as date)=cast(GETDATE() as date) then 1 else 0 end) 'Today<br>&nbsp;" . date('m/d') . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='1' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+1 day')), 0, 2).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+1 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='2' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+2 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+2 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='3' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+5 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+5 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='4' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+6 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+6 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='5' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+7 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+7 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='6' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+8 day')), 0, 2).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+8 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='7' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+9 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+9 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='8' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+12 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+12 day')) . "',
        sum(case when DATEDIFF(dd,cast(GETDATE() as date),cast(a.follow_up as date))='9' then 1 else 0 end) '" . substr(date('l/m/d', strtotime('+13 day')), 0, 1).'<br>' . date('m/d', strtotime('+13 day')) . "',
```

Comment: `strtotime("-".(date("N")-1)." days");` will take you back to monday, then use `strtotime("+1 day", $lastmonday);`

Comment: You could use `date("D m/d");` instead of chopping up "l/m/d"

Comment: That might be the answer I'm looking for waygood, i'll give it a go. Thank you.

Comment: or use a loop 1 - 14 and date("N") is not >5 ie 6-Satuday 7-Sunday

Comment: I had to look at what "N" did, ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0).

Comment: Yup so today is Wednesday N=3, N-1=2, today -2days is monday

Comment: I don't understand the variable $lastmonday

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29259/discussion-between-head-way-and-waygood)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

date('N') will give the day of the week in the format 1-Monday to 7-Sunday
So if we subtract 1 to give 0-6, then use that to go back days, it will take us back to last Monday.

ie monday=1, 1-1=0,  -0days is monday
   tuesday=2, 2-1=1,  -1days is monday
..
   friday=5, 5-1=4  -4days is monday

```
$lastmonday=strtotime("-".(date("N")-1)." days");
for($loop=0;$loop<14;$loop++)
{
    $theday=strtotime("+".$loop." days", $lastmonday);
    if(date("N", $theday)>5)
    {
       echo 'weekend';
    }
    else
    {
        echo date('D m/d'); 
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```